# 10-key (numeric keyboard) not working when connected via VNC to Fedora 35 or Ubuntu 21. Both are using GNOME - is this a bug?

Tags: gnome, vnc, vncviewer

I use VNC (RealVNC "VNC Viewer" app) on my Mac to connect to Linux desktops: Fedora 35 & Ubuntu 21. They both are using GNOME desktop: 41.1 for Fedora, and 40.5 for Ubuntu

I recently discovered that **the 10-key (numeric) part of my Mac keyboard no longer works on either desktop when connected via VNC**. These are both physical machines, but I have not yet tried actually connecting the same keyboard to the Linux machines yet since I need the VNC connection to work. [I have disabled "Mouse Keys"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4473/numeric-keypad-not-working) but this has no effect and did not resolve the issue.

Is this a bug in GNOME perhaps? Worth mentioning that the 10-key does work in Windows and macOS when connected via VNC. Also, for whatever reason the 10-key **does** work in the calculator app in Linux, but nothing else. When trying to use the 10-key to enter numbers in a text editor app I just get the "ding" error sound. When trying to use it in the terminal it prints outs all caps letters: for example - 123456789 shows:

`[me@fedora35 ~]$ BDECA`

I have reloaded the OS and the issue persists - this is a problem with my CLIENT machine (macOS), not the Linux VNC server (Fedora, Ubuntu, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem connecting from Windows 10 (Real VNC Viewer) to Linux Mint 20.2 running x11vnc. Calculator app works, terminal generates rubbish

I found a post in the Linux Mint forums that seems to solve the problem: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1936007#p1936007

1. Open keyboard settings
2. Click the tab, " layouts "
3. Click on the bottom " options ... "
4. Click "misc compatibility options" and check "numberic keys always enter digits"

I don't know if GNOME uses similar settings

Comment: are you also using GNOME for your desktop?

Comment: I'm using Linux Mint Cinnamon, which is, as far as I know, a fork of GNOME3

Comment: Thanks, @Edwin L. Unfortunately Fedora does not have any such options.